# Securing Spring Boot API with API key and secret-which is key and which is the secret

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, authentication

which one is key and which one is secret? Do I need add this to my application.properties file ?

```
@Value("${yourapp.http.auth-token-header-name}")
private String principalRequestHeader;

@Value("${yourapp.http.auth-token}")
private String principalRequestValue;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, that's just 5 lines of description, won't help others. Please elaborate your exact issue. And ofcourse if you have `@Value` you should have that value in application.yml

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to ad these into you application.properties files.
The first one is basically the "key" as header of the request. The second is the secret.